# How to output percentage distribution as a 2 dimension table in R?

Tags: r

I am using `RStudio` and I have a `dataframe` (`df1`).
`df1` contains several columns but I am interested with these 3 columns: `compname`, `dept`, `losYRS`.

I want to get the percentage distribution of each `compname` by `dept`.
My `R` codes stand as follows:

```
library(lubridate)
library(tidyverse)

df2<-(subset(df1,compName %in% c("A")))

df3<-df2 %>%
     group_by(dept) %>%
     summarise(count = n() / nrow(.) * 100 )
df3

# A tibble: 11 x 2
   dept              count
   <chr>             <dbl>
 1 F&B (Kitchen)     18.6 
 2 F&B (Restaurant)  20.3 
 3 FINANCE            5.08
 4 FRONT OFFICE      10.2 
 5 HOUSEKEEPING      22.0 
 6 HR                 1.69
 7 LEISURE AND SPORT  3.39
 8 MAINTENANCE        8.47
 9 RESERVATION        1.69
10 SPA                5.08
11 STEWARDING         3.39
```

Instead of sub-setting each time for each `dept`, is there a way to get the results as below (with or without the `Grand Total`):

[image: TABLE1]

I would also like to have the figures formatted for zero decimal places together with the % sign attached (as shown above).

Sample data (using dput):

```
structure(list(compName2 = c("A", "A", "C", 
"B", "C", "A", "A", "B", "B", 
"A", "C", "C", "A","B", "B", "A", "C", "C", 
"A", "B"), dept = c("MAINTENANCE", "OPERATIONS", 
"F&B (Kitchen)", "F&B (Kitchen)", "HOUSEKEEPING", "F&B (Restaurant)", 
"RESERVATION", "F&B (Restaurant)", "HOUSEKEEPING", "MAINTENANCE", 
"FRONT OFFICE", "HOUSEKEEPING", "MAINTENANCE", "HOUSEKEEPING", 
"MAINTENANCE", "F&B (Restaurant)", "HOUSEKEEPING", "F&B (Restaurant)", 
"F&B (Restaurant)", "MAINTENANCE"), losYRS = c(31, 30, 29, 28, 
28, 28, 28, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 26, 26, 26, 26, 26, 26, 25
)), .Names = c("compName", "dept", "losYRS"), row.names = c(NA, 
20L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Hi. Could u please provide a sample of your dataset with `dput`?

Comment: sample dataset using dput added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my solution to your problem with `tidyverse`:

```
library(tidyverse)

###Calculate percentages
df2 <- df %>% group_by(compName) %>% group_split(keep=T) %>% 
  map(group_by,dept) %>% map(function(x){summarize(x,perc = n()/nrow(x)*100,compName=x$compName[1])}) %>% bind_rows %>%
  spread(compName,perc)

###Added with base::split() for compatibility reasons:

df2 <- df %>% split(f=df$compName) %>%  map(group_by,dept) %>% map(function(x){summarize(x,perc = n()/nrow(x)*100,compName=x$compName[1])}) %>% bind_rows %>%
  spread(compName,perc)

##Create summary df for printing
print_df <- df2 %>% mutate_at(c("A","B","C"),round) %>% 
  bind_rows(df2 %>% replace(is.na(.),0) %>% summarize_at(c("A","B","C"),"sum") %>% mutate_all(round) %>%
              bind_cols(enframe("Grand Total",value="dept",name=NULL))) %>% mutate_at(c("A","B","C"),function(x){paste(as.character(x),"%")})

#print as tab-separated .txt-file
write.table(print_df,file="Test.txt",row.names=F)
```

Comment: Thanks. I am getting the following error: Error in group_split(., keep = T) : could not find function "group_split"

Comment: Did you use `library(tidyverse) `? It's a function from this package. Maybe you have to install it first?

Comment: Yes I used tidyverse library. May be a version issue?

Comment: Ok. Perfect. I just added a new version using `base::split` anyways